# Meteor pub/sub issues

Tags: meteor, simple-schema

This below is my collection code

```
Competitions = new Mongo.Collection("competitions");

var CompetitionsSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  year: {
      type: String
  },
  division: {
      type : String,
      allowedValues: ['Elite', '1st','2nd','3rd','4th','Intro']
  },
  teams:{
      type : [TeamSchema],
      allowedValues: (function () {
         return Teams.find().fetch().map(function (doc) {
            return doc.name;
        });
      }()) //here we wrap the function as expression and invoke it
  }
});
```

In the allowedValues function

> Teams.find is empty.

In the router I am subscribing to the publication as follows

```
 this.route('competitions', {
    path: '/admin/competitions',
    layoutTemplate: 'adminLayout',
    waitOn: function () {
        return [
            Meteor.subscribe('teams')
        ];
    }
});
```

This is my publish function

```
Meteor.publish('teams', function() {
  return  Teams.find({},{sort: {
    points: -1,
    netRunRate : -1
  }});
});
```

Do I have to do subscription some where else as well?

Comment: What does your publish function look like?

Comment: Just update my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in this piece of code:

```
  allowedValues: (function () {
     return Teams.find().fetch().map(function (doc) {
        return doc.name;
    });
  }()) //here we wrap the function as expression and invoke it
```

This gets called when the page loads. At that point the `Teams` collection will still be empty on the client side. You need to wait until the data is ready. Since you are using `waitOn` in iron-router, it might be enough to just move this code to the `onRendered` callback.

Comment: onRendered in the Template file? Like Template.ABC.Rendered? But I am defining it in the collection.